# Suggestions to a thermodynamics seminar presentation

Tags: thermodynamics

I have to present a work on thermodynamics, having to answer a question in this field in my freshman college year. Could you suggest any interesting question that could be used in my work? Unfortunately, all that i thought involved statistical mechanics and quantum mechanics, but probably it is not allowed...

The seminar presentation should take about ten minutes to present, so the question can not be so hard.

Comment: Does the question need to be novel, or can it have already been answered?

Comment: There may already be an answer :)

Comment: Then perhaps a question related to Maxwell's demon? The inter-relation between information in the demon's noggin and entropy of the system is something I have found quite interesting.

Comment: I'm going to presume you mean 'seminar', unless thermodynamics has become important to the priesthood... (Yes, I get it, either a translation or autocorrect issue, but then there is the whole pun of being indoctrinated into thermodynamics as well).

Comment: @JonCuster I just edited the question and replaced the word "seminary". I think it's a translation issue.

Comment: @wyphan - I agree, and am endlessly thankful I'm a native American speaker on the internet. My other options would be Latin, French, or Dutch and those just aren't particularly common. I can only hope it was taken in a lighthearted manner, because it did tweak my sense of humor.

Comment: Thank you @PrawwarP
I am from Brazil...
It was a false cognate ... I am happy when it happens, because it makes me never forget the meaning of the word :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try presenting the different types of real-life heat engines (diesel, rotary, ... ) and the underlying cycles (Stirling, Otto, Atkinson, ... ), and the advantages and disadvantages of each type. I think it would be interesting to explore why some engines are more popular than others, and for which applications they're used (for instance, car vs motorcycle vs airplane engines).

Or, you can try explaining why the ideal engine using the Carnot cycle doesn't exist in real life.